# Не работает генератор ТСР пакетов

Tags: c++, winsock, пакет

Здравствуйте!

Делаю лабораторную работу:

Реализация генератора TCP-пакетов(на Raw сокетах) в соответствии со стандартом RFC 793.

1. Требования к реализации

•   Приложение должно выполнять функции генерации TCP пакетов.
...
остальное не так важно...

Важно "руками" создать tcp пакет, и отправить его куда-то, допустим на 127.0.0.1 на порт 1000.

Кое-как собрал генератор пакетов... И он не работает... Не выдает ошибок при компиляции, а при работе sendto(...) WSAGetLastError() выдает ошибку 10022. Вот код:

```
header.h



 struct tcp_header
{
unsigned short  src_port;   // Порт отправителя
unsigned short  dst_port;   // Порт получателя 
unsigned int    seq_n;      // Номер очереди
unsigned int    ack_n;      // Номер подтверждения
unsigned char   offset;     // Смещение данных (4 бита) 
                    // + Зарезервировано (4 бита)
unsigned char   flags;      // Зарезервировано (2 бита) 
                    // + Флаги (6 бит)
unsigned short  win;        // Размер окна
unsigned short  crc;        // Контрольная сумма заголовка
unsigned short  padding;    // Дополнение до 20 байт
};
//Также необходимо ввести структуру псевдозаголовка, которая позволит вычислять контрольную сумму в TCP и UDP пакетах. 
struct pseudo_header
{
unsigned int src_addr;      // адрес отправителя 
unsigned int dst_addr;      // адрес получателя 
unsigned char zero ;        // начальная установка 
unsigned char proto;        // протокол
unsigned short length;      // длина заголовка 
//struct tcp_header tcp;
}; 

//-------=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
struct ip_header
{
unsigned char   ver_ihl;    // Длина заголовка (4 бита) 
                // (измеряется в словах по 32 бита) +
                // + Номер версии протокола (4 бита)
unsigned char   tos;        // Тип сервиса 
unsigned short  tlen;       // Общая длина пакета 
unsigned short  id;     // Идентификатор пакета
unsigned short  flags_fo;   // Управляющие флаги (3 бита) 
                    // + Смещение фрагмента (13 бит)
unsigned char   ttl;        // Время жизни пакета
unsigned char   proto;      // Протокол верхнего уровня 
unsigned short  crc;        // CRC заголовка
unsigned int    src_addr;   // IP-адрес отправителя
unsigned int    dst_addr;   // IP-адрес получателя
};

            ip_header iph;
                tcp_header tcph;
                    SOCKET s;

//-------=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//Далее поговорим о подсчете контрольных сумм в генерируемых пакетах. 
//Контрольную сумму в IP и ICMP пакетах считает следующая функция: 
unsigned short rs_crc (unsigned short * buffer, int length)
{
    unsigned long crc = 0;
    // Вычисление CRC 
    while (length > 1)
    {
        crc += *buffer++;
        length -= sizeof (unsigned short);
    }
    if (length) crc += *(unsigned char*) buffer;
    // Закончить вычисления 
    crc = (crc >> 16) + (crc & 0xffff);
    crc += (crc >> 16); 
    // Возвращаем инвертированное значение 
    return (unsigned short)(~crc); 
} 
//Для подсчета CRC в TCP и UDP пакетах необходимо воспользоваться следующей функцией, 
//которая сначала создает псевдозаголовок, а уже потом вычисляет контрольную сумму. 
unsigned short rs_pseudo_crc( char *data, int data_length,unsigned int src_addr,unsigned int dst_addr,int packet_length,unsigned char proto) 
{ 
    char * buffer; 
    unsigned int full_length; 
    unsigned char header_length;
    struct pseudo_header ph; 
    unsigned short p_crc = 0;

    // Заполнение структуры псевдозаголовка 
    ph.src_addr = src_addr; 
    ph.dst_addr = dst_addr; 
    ph.zero = 0; 
    ph.proto = proto;
    ph.length = htons (packet_length);

    header_length = sizeof (struct pseudo_header);

    full_length = header_length + data_length; 
    buffer =(char *) calloc (full_length, sizeof (char)); 

    // Генерация псевдозаголовка 
    memcpy (buffer, &ph, header_length); 
    memcpy (buffer + header_length, data, data_length); 

    // Вычисление CRC. 
    p_crc = rs_crc ((unsigned short*) buffer, full_length);
    free (buffer); 
    return p_crc;
} 
//Установки опции TOS для сокета:
int rs_set_tos (SOCKET s, unsigned char new_tos)
{
    int tos = new_tos;
    int tos_len = sizeof (tos);
    int per=setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, 3, (char *)&tos, tos_len);
    if (per == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"setsockopt Error "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    return 0;
}
//Установка опции RAW для сокета:
int rs_set_raw (SOCKET s)
{
    unsigned int use_own_header = 1;

    // Установка опции RAW для сокета, что говорит о том
    // что мы вручную будем формировать заголовки пакетов
    if ( setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, 2,//~IP_HDRINCL
        (char*)&use_own_header, sizeof(use_own_header))== SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"setsockopt Error "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    else
                        {
                                cout<<"TCP setsockopt - OK"<<endl;
                        }

    return 0;
}


//Далее необходимо объявить структуры заголовков создаваемых пакетов. 
//После этого производится заполнение заголовка IP пакета. На следующем шаге созданием RAW -сокет, 
//и если нет вложений протоколов верхнего уровня в пакет IP , то отправляем его, используя следующую функцию: 
int rs_send_ip (SOCKET s, ip_header iph, unsigned char * data, int data_length, unsigned short dst_port_raw)
{ 
    char * buffer;
    int result; 
    sockaddr_in target; 
    unsigned char header_length;
    unsigned int packet_length;
    memset (&target, 0, sizeof (target));
    target.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = iph.dst_addr; 
    target.sin_port = dst_port_raw; 

    // Вычисление длины и заголовка пакета 
    header_length = sizeof (struct ip_header); 
    packet_length = header_length + data_length; 

    // Установка CRC. 
    iph.crc = 0; 

    // Заполнение некоторых полей заголовка IP
    iph.ver_ihl = RS_IP_VERSION;

    // Если длина пакета не задана, то длина пакета 
    // приравнивается к длине заголовка 
    if (!(iph.ver_ihl & 0x0F)) 
        iph.ver_ihl |= 0x0F & (header_length / 4);
    buffer =(char *) calloc (packet_length, sizeof (char)); 

    // Копирование заголовка пакета в буфер ( CRC равно 0). 
    memcpy (buffer, &iph, sizeof (struct ip_header));

    // Копирование данных в буфер 
    if (data) memcpy (buffer + header_length, data,
                data_length); 

    // Вычисление CRC. 
    iph.crc = rs_crc((unsigned short *) buffer, 
                packet_length); 

    // Копирование заголовка пакета в буфер (CRC посчитана). 
    memcpy (buffer, &iph, sizeof (struct ip_header)); 

    // Отправка IP пакета в сеть.
    result = sendto ( s, buffer, packet_length, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&target,sizeof (target));

    if(result==SOCKET_ERROR)
        cout<<"TCP pakcet sended - Filed: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"TCP sendto - OK"<<endl;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    free (buffer);
    return result;
} 

int rs_send_tcp (SOCKET s, unsigned char * data, int data_length)
{ 
    char * buffer; 
    int result; 
    unsigned char header_length; 
    unsigned int packet_length; 

    // Вычисление длин пакета и заголовка.
    header_length = sizeof (struct tcp_header);
    packet_length = header_length + data_length; 

    // Установка CRC. 
    tcph.crc = 0; 

    // Установка поля offset .
    tcph.offset = 0xF0 & ((header_length / 4) << 4);
    buffer =(char *) calloc (packet_length, sizeof (char)); 

    // Копирование заголовка пакета в буфер ( CRC равно 0). 
    memcpy (buffer, &tcph, sizeof (struct tcp_header)); 

    // Копирование протокола более высокого уровня (данных) 
    if (data) memcpy (buffer + header_length, data, data_length); 

    // Вычисление CRC. 
    tcph.crc = rs_pseudo_crc (buffer, packet_length, iph.src_addr, iph.dst_addr, packet_length, IPPROTO_TCP); 

    // Копирование заголовка пакета в буфер (CRC посчитано).
    memcpy (buffer, &tcph, sizeof (struct tcp_header)); 

    // Посылка IP пакета с вложенным TCP пакетом 
    result = rs_send_ip (s, iph, (unsigned char*)buffer, packet_length, tcph.dst_port); 

    free (buffer);
    return result; 
}

int rs_exit(void)
{
    // Закрытие библиотеки Winsock
    if(!WSACleanup ())
        cout<<"TCP WSACleanup() - OK"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"TCP WSACleanup() Error "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

//=======================================================================================
    TCP.cpp

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#include "defines.h"
#include "header.h"


/*****************************************************************/
void ShowError()
{
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,WSAGetLastError(),
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,0,NULL);
        CharToOem((char*)lpMsgBuf,(char*)lpMsgBuf);
        cout<<(LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf<<endl;
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

//*****************************************************************/

void main(){
        WSADATA            wsaData;
        //Первым шагом будет инициализация библиотеки Winsock 2.2. 
        if(WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsaData)){ShowError();}
        else
        {
                cout<<"TCP WSAStartup - OK"<<endl;
                // Созлание RAW сокета.
                s = WSASocket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

            if(s != INVALID_SOCKET){

                cout<<"TCP Raw scoket is created"<<endl;

                rs_set_tos(s, 0);
                rs_set_raw(s);

    unsigned int use_own_header = 1;

    // Установка опции RAW для сокета, что говорит о том
    // что мы вручную будем формировать заголовки пакетов
    if ( setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, 2,//~IP_HDRINCL
        (char*)&use_own_header, sizeof(use_own_header))== SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"setsockopt Error "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    }
    else
                        {
                                cout<<"TCP setsockopt - OK"<<endl;
                        }


                char *ptr, szMessage[4068];
                strcpy(szMessage,"HHHHHHHHEEEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW");
                ptr=szMessage;
                unsigned char data; 
                data = static_cast<unsigned char>(*ptr);
                //************************************************************************

                rs_send_tcp (s, &data, strlen(ptr));


                if(closesocket(s)== SOCKET_ERROR){ cout<<"Close TCP Socket - Error"<<endl;}
                else{cout<<"TCP closesocket - OK"<<endl;}
            }
        }

        rs_exit();
        getch();
}
```

Подправил код... Вот тут вот // Отправка IP пакета в сеть.

```
    result = sendto ( s, buffer, packet_length, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&target,sizeof (target)); выявляется ошибка...
```

Перебрал всё заново руками, результат-меньше кода, а ошибка та же самая...:

```
char datagram[4096];
struct ip_header *iph = (struct ip_header *) datagram;


struct tcp_header *tcph = (struct tcp_header *) datagram + sizeof (struct ip_header);
char * data = (char *) datagram + sizeof(struct tcp_header) + sizeof(struct ip_header);
struct sockaddr_in sin;
WSADATA            wsaData;

//Первым шагом будет инициализация библиотеки Winsock 2.2. 
if(WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsaData))
    {ShowError();}
else
    cout<<"\n\nTCP WSAStartup - OK"<<endl;
        // Созлание RAW сокета.
SOCKET r = WSASocket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

if(r != INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout<<"TCP Raw scoket is created"<<endl;
}


sin.sin_family          = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port            = htons (1000);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr     = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

memset(datagram, 0, 4096);

iph->ver_ihl                    = 5;
iph->tos                     = 0;
iph->tlen                     = sizeof (struct ip_header) + sizeof (struct tcp_header);
iph->flags_fo                     = 0;
iph->ttl                    = 255;
iph->proto                       = 6;
iph->crc                    = 0;
iph->src_addr     = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
iph->dst_addr     = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;

tcph->src_port          = htons (1001);
tcph->dst_port          = htons (1000);
tcph->seq_n            = 65;// random
tcph->ack_n            = 0;
tcph->offset            = 0;
tcph->flags          = TCP_SYN;
tcph->win           = htonl (65535);
tcph->crc           = 0;
tcph->padding            = 0;

iph->crc             = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tlen >> 1);

memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));

unsigned int use_own_header = 1;
int one = 1;
const char *val = "hhhhhhh";
if(setsockopt (r,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,(char*)&use_own_header,sizeof(use_own_header))==SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout<< "Setsockopt\tFAIL.\n";
}

while(1) {
       int result = sendto ( r, data, strlen(data), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof (sin));
        if(result==SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
                cerr << "Sendto\tFAIL. "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
        } else
                cout << " :) ";
}
```

Comment: минус за неправильное использование тэгов (уж пора бы научиться - сколько раз просили)...

Comment: @Alerr Invalid argument

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924071.aspx

Comment: под вопросом которые и отмечают тематическую направленность вопроса (c++, winsock, visual-studio-2010). Напоминаю, что ["C++"][1] - не то же самое, что ["С++"][2] (поисковик считает их разными тэгами)

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B/
[2]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/%D1%81%2B%2B/

Comment: Можно и без C++.

    yes 'Фиг вам!' | nc $host $port

где переменные host и port содержат адрес и номер порта приёмника. А вообще, зачем у Вас какие-то raw  и пр. Подправьте вопрос, добавьте туда задание лабораторной. А то вычислять что данная программа должна делать, охотников вряд ли много найдётся.

Comment: Нет, нужно на с++ и с Raw сокетами... Задача именно в создании пакета "руками". Пока мне не понятно зачем вообще нужен псевдозаголовок и что и как с ним делать...

Comment: Слушайте, это так чтение hashcode.ru влияет, или характер вопросов обусловлен другими причинами? Почему хочется иногда задающих вопросы затащить в пыточную, чтобы они сразу выдали максимум информации о своём вопросе? Вот и из Вас, @Alerr, приходится эту информацию выдавливать по капле.

Comment: @Alerr, разбираться в Вашей простыне просто неохота.


Вы описание ошибки нашли?
    
    WSAEINVAL
    10022
    
    Invalid argument.
    
        Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying  an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

Мне кажется, что проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь послать TCP пакет данных, а коннект не сделан.

Скорее всего Вам надо использовать UDP, и отправить 1 пакет, а Вы приписали сокету TCP опции.

Comment: Так мне же не UDP пакет надо послать, а именно TCP

Comment: А Вы RFC 793 сначала прочтите. 

Перед посылкой пакета с данными надо обменяться несколькими служебными пакетами с сервером.

Comment: Читал его... Так мне вроде просто послать надо и всё... Генератор пакетов только шлет пакеты, разве не так?

Comment: Ну, если только послать, а дальше "хоть трава не расти...".

Вот здесь [пример](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-c-code-linux/). Работает или нет, не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, а генератор должен только слать же? А если установить соединение то как быть? Есть какой-нибудь пример только для windows и на с++? Я сам уже все выходные безуспешно ищу... rfc 793 не содержит примеров кода....

Comment: rfc793 содержит диаграмму состояний и диаграммы обмена пакетами в том или ином случае. Но что Вы в конечном счёте хотите -- остаётся непонятным. Если Вы хотите использовать системную реализацию TCP, то откуда raw socket. Возможно вы хотите сами реализовать TCP и поверх этой реализации написать генератор пакетов?

Comment: Та же самая -- это какая?

Comment: @Alerr, вот по запросу в гугл 

    raw socket receive example

нашел [интересный материал](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/)

Кстати, других толковых статей тоже много.

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание, речь именно о **send**.

Limitations on Raw Sockets

On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:

```
TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.
UDP datagrams with an invalid source address cannot be sent over raw sockets. The IP source address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist on a network interface or the datagram is dropped. This change was made to limit the ability of malicious code to create distributed denial-of-service attacks and limits the ability to send spoofed packets (TCP/IP packets with a forged source IP address).
A call to the bind function with a raw socket for the IPPROTO_TCP protocol is not allowed.

Note  The bind function with a raw socket is allowed for other protocols (IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_UDP, or IPPROTO_SCTP, for example).
```

These above restrictions do not apply to Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 , Windows Server 2003, or to versions of the operating system earlier than Windows XP with SP2.

см. [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (от Microsoft).

Comment: Спсаибо за материал) Вот значит как они борются с флудерами-спуферами))))))) Получается на виндовс можно отправлять пакеты, только вот source ip у них должны быть реальные?

Comment: Такой вот вопрос возик... Собираю я пакет, отправляю sendto пытаюсь в winshark его как-то увидеть и вообще ничего не вижу( Другие пакеты вижу... А свой, собранный "руками", не вижу.. Может виншарк не видит плохо собранные пакеты? Скорее всего из-за неправильности заполнения пакета сниффер принимает его не за тср пакет?, да и вообще не за пакет принимает... Может такое быть?